# When I try to install ipa on my iphone it says "kAMDDeviceFamilyNotSupported"

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ipa

I was installing ipa via itunes and it shows this error - kAMDDeviceFamilyNotSupported

Comment: It looks like you're trying to ask a question. Would you like some help with that? •[Ask] •[Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) •No, thanks, just close this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just checked the xcode settings,under project summary->Devices , ipad was selected and was installing the build on iphone.

Its working now.